# Display the Day only in my TextBlock from DateTime property

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I want to display Day only in my TextBlock from the DateTime property in my WindowsPhone application.I use the following code to display the Day in the TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedValue,StringFormat='dd'}"
           FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

But when i select the 1st day it displays like **01** But i want it to be displayed like **1**
Is there any way to do this using `StringFormat`.

I expect this should be achieved using 100% xaml code not even using converter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `d` format character specifies a day of the month without a leading zero. However, you need something (anything) else to make sure it isn't interpreted as the standard `d` date format string. One way would be to precede it by an empty string: `String.Format(DateTime.Today, "''d")` shows up as 14. In XAML, you will need to encode the single quote character. When testing in WPF, it turns out to be much easier to get it working with the same quote characters as the outermost ones, due to escape issues, so it becomes

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedValue,StringFormat='d&quot;&quot;'}"
       FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

**Edit**: perhaps a cleaner and simpler way would be to not bind to the date at all, but to bind directly to the day of the month:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedValue.Day}"
       FontWeight="Bold"/>
```